# Give a button a pre set "Style" in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, intellij-idea

Is there a way to set out what you want a button style to be then use this pre made style settings on all/certain buttons. For instance have a couple pre set button styles that you are able to set groups of buttons to have instead of having to change all the style settings for each button individually. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Pluggable Look and Feel + Java + Tutorial

Comment: You could also use a static buttons factory and get all buttons instances from it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've now created a method which customises a given button. So can easily call this for each button. Not sure if that the right thing to do but seems to work fine so far and decreases the amount of code I have to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a custom button by extending JButton and use that one instead

```
public class CustomButton extends JButton {

    public CustomButtong(String text) {
        super(text);
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

}
```

Now you can import the class and use it just like a JButton, for example

```
CustomButton button = new CustomButton("Click me!");
```

You can modify the constructor to your needs.